# pymysql - Can't connect to MySQL server "Temporary failure" in name resolution

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, pymysql

I'm trying to connect to MySQL database that is hosted on our AWS-RDS instance through Python using pymysql. I am able to connect and retrieve data successfully but the connection intermittently drops and throws error 
`"pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '<my_hostname>' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)")"`

Please note that I'm using Python's multiprocessing library to run pool processes. All the threads created by this process are trying to access database. The process runs for a while and then loses connection to MySQL, at random intervals for different runs.

- Tried putting RDS url directly in the client code
- Tried opening separate cursors for separate DB queries made within the code.

```py
return list(tqdm(pool.imap(createMetricDataJson,res), total=len(res)))
```

createMetricDataJson method calls database to query different tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR AWS Lambda SDK: Temporary failure in name resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64652069/error-aws-lambda-sdk-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of the default 8-hour timeout limit on MySQL database, if no activity is posted. This can be resolved by sending a heartbeat to MySQL at regular intervals.