# ERROR AWS Lambda SDK: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-vpc

In a AWS lambda during a burst application process. We create and run about 4k lambdas within a VPC. This lambda is copying a file from one AWS account to another. During a burst of invocations > 4k, <5k we have noticied all boto3 client account starts failing.

At some point we start to recieve

> urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
> <botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab54f6ae20>:
> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in
> name resolution botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not
> connect to the endpoint URL: "https://.s3.amazonaws.com/"

Followed by what was previously successful, but now also erroring:

> Recieved following error
>
> n Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://sts.amazonaws.com/"
> [ERROR] 2020-11-02T18:50:05.867Z b2bc9529-0ea5-40f1-ba0e-98d9cf26eb2c
> Recieved following error n Could not connect to the endpoint URL:
> "https://sts.amazonaws.com/"

After the burst these errors go away.

I would like to know what the problem is here so that I can start resolving this problem, but I do not know where to start looking?

I did find this question which seems like to my problem: [Occasional 'temporary failure in name resolution' while connecting to AWS Aurora cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179080/occasional-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-while-connecting-to-aws-aurora) although with this answer it is not clear to me what exactly do I when I cannot connect to AWS services anymore?

Looking at VPC flow logs I do logs during this timeframe with:

> 2 unknown eni-034e0bc6a93976fcb - - - - - - - 1604344032 1604344205 -
> NODATA

and

> 2 unknown eni-034e0bc6a93976fcb 10.XXX.XX.XXX 10.XXX.XX.XXX 45844 2049
> 6 10 866 1604344061 1604344176 ACCEPT OK

But I have no idea what it means or if it indicates a problem.

Comment: Hi @vfrank66, just wondering if you had any luck with resolving this issue?

Comment: I agree with your answer @mikey although we currently do not use AWS Hyperplane so I ignored that part, and I also agree with jarmod's answer. We have not completely fixed the packet limit. We already have hundreds of ENI's in our subnet's which is a hard request for hosting to allow more. Currently we are adding retry logic since it is only temporarily. 

Another problem that can cause this which I read somewhere is that the hardware being used could be failing or faulting. I could be wrong but I believe that since it sounds like it could be accurate.

Comment: So no luck to directly answer your question. Due to increased AWS use we are also experiencing this is AWS Batch which is using ec2 cluster's within the VPC,vpc config with subnets.

Comment: FYI AWS HyperPlane is an _internal_ service that powers AWS services such as NAT, PrivateLink, Load Balancers, and EFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a DNS request quota issue. See [DNS quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-limits).

Also, see [Occasional 'temporary failure in name resolution' while connecting to AWS Aurora cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179080/occasional-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-while-connecting-to-aws-aurora) for discussion and some proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback on my answer to the question: [Occasional 'temporary failure in name resolution' while connecting to AWS Aurora cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179080/occasional-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-while-connecting-to-aws-aurora/59940370#59940370). Since the time I posted that answer, we have tackled the problem by increasing the number of ENIs created by [AWS Hyperplane](https://youtu.be/dfEcd3zqPOA?t=4661).

As you hinted at, and [jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271415/jarmod) noted: There is maximum number - 1024 per ENI, of packets that can be sent to the Amazon Route 53 Resolver in one second.

Interestingly, while this number is a **hard limit**, it is relative to a single ENI. So increasing the number of ENIs would allow you to send more packets, per second, to the Amazon Route 53 Resolver. The number of ENIs used by Lambda can be increased by increasing the number of *security group:subnet combinations* in your VPC. Two ways to achieve this are:

- Attaching distinct security groups to distinct Lambda functions
- Hosting your Lambda functions in multiple subnets

Finally, it is important to understand how and when AWS Hyperplane creates  ENIs:

> Hyperplane now creates a shared network interface when your Lambda function is first created or when its VPC settings are updated, improving function setup performance and scalability. This one-time setup can take up to 90 seconds to complete

See [Improved VPC Networking for AWS Lambda Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/) for more information on AWS Hyperplane, *security group:subnet combinations* and their relationship to ENIs.

Love Mikey :)